# I want to split a number into single digit and change it into the binary in android

Tags: java, android

I have a number 83 I want to split this number like 8 and 3 then want to change the number into binary form in android and want the result.how can I do this.Please help me

Thanks

Comment: http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/DataConversion.shtml , 
http://www.ehow.com/how_8708889_convert-integer-binary-array-java.html.. Look at these links if you are looking for tutorials

Comment: Convert int into String & then by using getCharArray(), split the characters and then use Integer.toBinaryString

Comment: You need to explain more.  Are you saying that you want each separate digit represented as binary? In one string or separate strings.  An example would be good.  Are you looking for 1000, 0011 or 10000011 or something else?

Comment: Into *what* binary form? 0x8? 0x3? 0x53? 0x83?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public String conIntTOBin(String num) {
        String temp = "";

        for(int i=0; i < num.length(); i++) {                               
              temp += Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(""+num.charAt(i)));
        }
        return temp;

 }
```

pass your integer number as a string perametre.

Answer (score 7):

You can convert an `integer` value to `binaryString` using [`Integer.toBinaryString(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29).

Now, to split your integer into individual digits, you can use simple mathematics using `modulus (%)` and `division (/)` operators.

Here's the recursive function that you can use: -

```
public static void convert(int num) {

    if (num > 0) {
        int lastDigit = num % 10;
        convert(num / 10);
        System.out.print(Integer.toBinaryString(lastDigit) + " ");
    }
}

// From your main method
convert(83);
```

**OUTPUT: -**

```
1000 11
```

Comment: Downvoter can you please comment? Its not worth to downvote, if you are not pointing the problem with the answer

Comment: And another +1 to restore the natural balance of the Androidverse.

Answer (score 1):

To Get Digits from a number use following method:

```
String str = String.valueOf(someInt);

char[] digits = str.toCharArray();
```

now itereate through digits array. and convert each digit to binary, by

```
Integer.toBinaryString(Character.digit(digits[i], 10));
```

Comment: to convert a number to string, and then get char array from that string

Comment: Your `digit[i]` is a character.. And `toBinaryString` method is not defined in `Character` class.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, although, char itself an integer type, but the value digits[i], returns unicode value of character, so I edited code accordingly.

Comment: Is it worth to change the integer first to characters and later process it back... I think it will take more processing and time to execute your logic instead logic mentioned by Rohit... Anyway I got another way to solve this issue.. Thanks